# Change to the multiple-cycle implementation that alters the register file so that it has only one read port

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-architecture

single read port: [image: single read port]

For the sw instruction, in the 3rd cycle the RegRead does not need to be set to 1;

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. You mention a change in your title, and a specific type of change in your question, but I don't see any more than that. Also, this may not be a programming question. Please read [ask].

Comment: Where can I ask this question?
Concerns the theory of multicycle datapath. With the photo the question becomes more understandable

Comment: Questions about cpu-architecture / cpu-design can be on-topic on Stack Overflow (@ThomasJager).  The problem with this question isn't the topic, it's the lack of details and clarity, and lack of evidence of any attempt for what looks like a homework question. ([How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822))

Answer (score 3):

The `sw` instruction has two register sources, as does an `add` instruction.

The `add` needs to obtain both sources in ID phase (cycle if multicycle or stage if pipelined), so that their values can be added in the next phase, EX.

But `sw` only needs to obtain `rs` (and the `imm`) in the ID phase, so that they can be added in the next phase (EX).  Obtaining the `rt` register (the value for Write Data) can be delayed until the EX phase, because the actual store doesn't happen until the next phase after EX, the MEM phase.

So, while delaying read of `rt` can reduce the read port on the register file to one for the `sw` instruction, it does nothing for the `add` instruction — in order to reduce to one read port for all instructions, we would have to insert an additional phase.

Further, this approach would only work for a multicycle machine, but a pipelined machine would require some other approach since all the phases (the pipeline stages) overlap — spreading reads for one instruction out across multiple cycles doesn't lighten the load on the register file.